# Ubuntu script never ending loop

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I have just started scripting for college and I am trying to make a menu that runs some functions when selected. For now I'm just trying to get a menu to appear but it gets stuck in a infinite loop. I am not good at scripting at all but really need to learn it for the course.

```
while true
do
    echo "1) option1"
    echo "2) option2"
    echo "3) option3"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, in while loop in condition's place you are providing `true` which means condition will always be TRUE and thus a infinite loop for.

Answer (score 1):

For menus in shell, use the `select` statement:

```
PS3='Select your choice: '
select ans in "option1" "option2" "option3" quit
do
    case $ans in
        option1) do_something ;;
        option2) do_something ;;
        option3) do_something ;;
        quit) break ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop in condition's place you are providing `true` which means condition will always be TRUE and thus a infinite loop for.

This is how `while` loop works:

```
while condition
if condition is TRUE--> then go inside loop and do operations as per instructions in it.
if condition is FALSE--> then come out of loop since the given condition is no more.
```

Example of very basic `while` loop:

```
while ((i<=3))
do
  echo "Hey there..."
  ((i = i +1 ))
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Hey there...
Hey there...
Hey there...
Hey there...
```

Comment: My lecturer added the "while true" which confused me because it doesn't have any condition which is where I am confused. What would you recommend I could use as a condition because everything I have tried hasn't worked?

Comment: @J.walker, I added a basic example of `while` loop, you can search SO forum itself to get more examples of this too.